# Is there an .ogg plugin for quicklook?

Tags: quicklook

Is there one of these?

I could not find one with a basic search on google.

If not, is it possible to make it look and behave exactly like the default audio quicklook in objective-C?

Answer (score 6):

Whenever I want a new Quicklook plugin, I look through three places:

1. [quicklookplugins.com](http://www.quicklookplugins.com/)
2. <strike>qlplugins.com</strike>
3. And a [specially crafted google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=quick+look+plugins+ogg).

Neither of the third party quick look plugin sites list any results for 'ogg' or 'vorbis', and the link to bravobug.com in [a MacWorld forum post](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=83997) no longer works either because the domain has been squatted, or the blog software has just become completely overrun by spam, which is also why I didn't actually link directly to blog post.

Xiph (the company responsible for OGG and so much more) created the [XiphQT](http://xiph.org/quicktime/) components forever ago, but they haven't been updated in years, and there's no updates to suggest QLPlugins or anything else of the sort.

It seems like this does not exist. Unfortunately.

Comment: Lol (the specially crafted Google search).

Comment: This article is only the #3 hit for the specially crafted Google search.

Comment: #2 appears to now be a squatted domain with a spammy boilerplate WordPress running on it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unlinked and visibly killed, otherwise preserving content for later reference if desired.

Answer (score -1):

[XiphQT](http://www.xiph.org/quicktime/) works! Install it and Quick Look plays ogg files.  Tested on Mountain Lion.